# How does one create tabsets for H2 Elements in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

How do you create a tabset for H2Elements in Angularjs. Can someone provide an example ?

Comment: What did you try? What did not work?

Comment: I did not try anything as I don't know what to do

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use AngularJS to create tabs. It stands for MVC approach and separate UI from action processing. You should use CSS for UI rendering. AngularJS can help you e.g. to maintain navigation between tabs. I can recommend you [an example](http://www.onextrapixel.com/examples/pure-css-tab-with-fade-animation/index.html) which create tabs from **UL/LI** elements. No big difference if you would like to make tabs from **H2** elements. Just change stylesheet.